# How do I get a relation for a model that belongs_to another model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two models: `Option` and `Answer`.  An option `has_many :answers` and an answer `belongs_to :option`.  I have a variable called @answers:

```
@answers = Answer.where(content: 'a')
```

I now need to get a relation with all of the options that relate to @answers.  I have tried:

```
@options = @answers.joins(:option)
```

But this returns an array of answers, not options.  How do I get a relation of options from @answers?

Answer (score 1):

```
Option.joins(:answers).where(answers: { content: 'a' })
```

Or less efficient:

```
Option.joins(:answers).where(answers: { id: @answers.pluck(:id) })
```

Or without join:

```
Option.where(id: @answers.pluck(:option_id).uniq)
```

Or use a scope on the Answer class and merge:

```
scope :with_content ->(content) { where(content: content) }

Option.joins(:answers).merge(Answer.with_content('a'))
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to use the @answers variable.  This is close but still doesn't do it

Comment: and I get this answer with your second choice: NoMethodError: undefined method `pluck' for #<Answer:0x007fdf592c1880>

Comment: Can you do this: Answer.where(content: 'a').pluck(:id) ? It sounds like your @answers is different then the one you give in your example. If you have a single answer (which seems the case in the error you show) you can simply call option on it.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `option` method:

```
@answers = Answer.where(content: 'a').map(&:option)
```

Comment: That won't work for a relation.  It returns an array but I need it to return a relation

Comment: Thanks Josh.  I edited my first comment to respond to your new answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the `@answers`, do this to a better performance:

```
@answers = Answer.where(content: 'a')
@options = Option.where('id in (?)', @answers.map(&:option_id).uniq)
```

This way you're going to to only 2 queries (avoiding n+1)

Comment: id should be answers.id here. I would also use pluck instead of map.

Comment: He told he need the `@answers` when you do a pluck, that will perform a database query to select the id. You don't need to do that if you already have an array with the ids.

Comment: With map you are loading a ton of objects. If you measure performance I'm pretty sure pluck will come on top.

Comment: But Phillip wants the `@answers` array, so you already have all the objects on memory. Between using an already instantiated object or do a new database query, I would choose don't hit the database again.

Comment: A better solution would be `@options = Option.where('id in (?)', Answer.where(content: 'a').pluck('distinct option_id'))`, but this way he will not have the `@answers`

Comment: True, the whole @answers part is a bit of a mystery though. We don't know the context, but I have a feeling he really wants to use his answers instance variable where it might not even be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do

```
@answers = Answer.where(content: 'a')
@options = @answers.options.find(params[:id])
```

..or whatever options param you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

You could eager load 'option' associated to each answer

```
@answers = Answer.where(content: 'a').includes(:option)
```

And then get the options without running a query,

```
@options = @answers.map(&:option)
```

Note that this returns an array of activerecord relations, not simply an array.